# Catching word if it doesn't start with some other word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a log file and find error related lines. I come up a line like this one:

```
Worker Node UP/DOWN Notification received From ICM-GW
```

where its a notification, not and error, I want to find lines with **DOWN** info in it but exclude if **UP/DOWN** is present. I try many regex expressions but couldn't get even closer. 
Any help will be very helpful.

```
([?!up\/]?(down))
```

Comment: Use `r'(?i)\b(?<!\bup/)down\b'`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LM0me4/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working. you can put as answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[?!up\/]?` is a character class that matches `?`, or `!`, `u`, `p` or `/`, 1 or 0 times (due to the `?` quantifier after `]`, it makes this pattern optional).

You may use a lookbehind based regex like

```
r'(?i)\b(?<!\bup/)down\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LM0me4/1)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `\b` - a word boundary (to avoid matching `down` in `touchdown`)
- `(?<!\bup/)` - no whole word `up` is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `down` - `down` char sequence
- `\b` - a word boundary, immediately to the right, there cannot be any word char (letter, digit or `_`, and some others since `re.U` flag is on by default in Python 3, but they are not that relevant).